# How to get a dump of all vectors from a gensim W2V model?

Tags: python, vector, gensim, word2vec

Using a [KeyedVectors](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html) object, I can get the W2V vector, given a word, like so.

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

model = KeyedVectors.load('vectors.kv')
model.get_vector('example')  # output => [0.12, 0.41, ..., 0.92]
```

How can I do the same, for *every* term (key) contained in the model?

*Note that this doesn't *have* to be a KeyedVectors object, it could alternatively be a [Word2Vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) object.*

**EDIT** - thanks to gojomo:

```
vector_dct = {}
for word in kv_model.index2word: 
    vector_dct[word] = kv_model.get_vector(word)

df = pd.DataFrame(vector_dct).T
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
for word in kv_model.index_to_key:  # was kv_model.index2word pre-gensim-4.0.0, when Q 1st asked
    kv_model.get_vector(word)
```

Comment: According to the (recent) docs: "The index2word attribute has been replaced by index_to_key since Gensim 4.0.0. See https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4"

Comment: Indeed, as is already mentioned in the code-comment! But I'll reverse the code & comment, so the code matches recent Gensim, & comment mentions earlier (contemporaneous to question) name.

Comment: Oh, my bad ‍♂️ I have to start the habit of reading the comments.